# SQL - Join Expression Not Supported

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new using Access and trying to change this query:

```
SELECT 
   DateDiff("d", [Invoice]![TxnDate],[ReceivePaymentLine]![TxnDate]) AS ActualPaymentDays, 
   IIF ([ActualPaymentDays] < 90, 0.10, IIF ([ActualPaymentDays] < 120, 0.09, IID ([ActualPaymentDays] , 365, 0.05, 0))) AS PayPerValue
FROM 
   ReceivePaymentLine 
INNER JOIN 
   Invoice ON ReceivePaymentLine.AppliedToTxnTxnID = Invoice.TxnID
```

I make "ActualPaymentDaysRate" table:

```
ActualPaymentDay1
PayPerValue1
ActualPaymentDay2
PayPerValue2
ActualPaymentDay3
PayPerValue3
```

And I change the query above to be this query:

```
SELECT 
    DateDiff("d",[Invoice]![TxnDate],[ReceivePaymentLine]![TxnDate]) AS ActualPaymentDays, 
    IIF ([ActualPaymentDays] < [ActualPaymentDaysRate.ActualPaymentDay1],[ActualPaymentDaysRate.PayPerValue1], IIF ([ActualPaymentDays] < [ActualPaymentDaysRate.ActualPaymentDay2], [ActualPaymentDaysRate.PayPerValue2], IIF ([ActualPaymentDays] < [ActualPaymentDaysRate.ActualPaymentDay3],[ActualPaymentDaysRate.PayPerValue3], 0))) AS PayPerValue
FROM 
    ActualPaymentDaysRate, ReceivePaymentLine 
INNER JOIN 
    Invoice ON ReceivePaymentLine.AppliedToTxnTxnID = Invoice.TxnID
```

It shows error "JOIN expression not supported".

Comment: Maybe because JON has nothing to do with "INNER JOIN"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did type "JOIN" in my Access and shows that error. Sorry I made mistake typing "JON" here on this forum (I worked using Microsoft Access on other computer without internet connection, that's why I could not copy and paste the query).

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix-n-match old style and new style join syntax.

Add another join:

```
SELECT DateDiff("d",[Invoice]![TxnDate],[ReceivePaymentLine]![TxnDate]) AS ActualPaymentDays, IIF ([ActualPaymentDays] < [ActualPaymentDaysRate.ActualPaymentDay1],[ActualPaymentDaysRate.PayPerValue1],IIF ([ActualPaymentDays] < [ActualPaymentDaysRate.ActualPaymentDay2],[ActualPaymentDaysRate.PayPerValue2], IIF ([ActualPaymentDays] < [ActualPaymentDaysRate.ActualPaymentDay3],[ActualPaymentDaysRate.PayPerValue3], 0))) AS PayPerValue
FROM ReceivePaymentLine
INNER JOIN Invoice ON ReceivePaymentLine.AppliedToTxnTxnID = Invoice.TxnID
JOIN ActualPaymentDaysRate ON {some condition}
```

Also, you spelled JOIN as "JON" in your query. I corrected that in this one.

Comment: The problem is: Not sure how to make the "ON {some condition}". ActualPaymentDaysRate table has only one record (and the field of "ActualPaymentDay1, ActualPaymentDay2, ActualPaymentDay3 are related to DateDiff("d",[Invoice]![TxnDate],[ReceivePaymentLine]![TxnDate]) AS ActualPaymentDays. I want to make dynamic IF (Now the IF condition for ActualPaymentDays<90, ActualPaymentDays<120 and ActualPaymentDays<365 are all hardcode on query). I want Admin to be able to change those numbers (90, 120 and 365) on the data table (ActualPaymentDaysRate) then run the report.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong is using both **ANSI SQL-89** Syntax and **ANSI SQL-92** Syntax for JOIN

The old syntax for `INNER JOIN` which is **ANSI SQL-89** is in which you specify both table names seprated by comma which you done in your query like this

```
SELECT <column list>
FROM ActualPaymentDaysRate, ReceivePaymentLine
```

The **ANSI SQL-92** syntax is in which you use `JOIN` keyword and specify condition using `ON` which you have done like

```
 INNER JOIN Invoice ON ReceivePaymentLine.AppliedToTxnTxnID = Invoice.TxnID
```

BUT you cannot use them at same time in same query.
In your query you have three tables and hence use three `INNER JOIN` to link the tables.

Using ANSI SQL-89 syntax is not recommended becuse if you forget about joining condition , no error is generated , instead a cartesian product is applied between the tables returning all the rows.

```
SELECT <column list>
FROM ActualPaymentDaysRate, ReceivePaymentLine 
--  WHERE <condition> excluded , NOT a INNER JOIN anymore but still no error
```

But if you forget condition in SQL-92 syntax , immediately error is generated.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your explanation. Any idea how to fix my query? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you've specified two table names in inner join, you need two inner join to join 3 tables.

See this.

```
SELECT DateDiff("d",[Invoice]![TxnDate],[ReceivePaymentLine]![TxnDate]) AS ActualPaymentDays, 
IIF ([ActualPaymentDays] < [ActualPaymentDaysRate.ActualPaymentDay1],[ActualPaymentDaysRate.PayPerValue1],
IIF ([ActualPaymentDays] < [ActualPaymentDaysRate.ActualPaymentDay2],[ActualPaymentDaysRate.PayPerValue2], 
IIF ([ActualPaymentDays] < [ActualPaymentDaysRate.ActualPaymentDay3],[ActualPaymentDaysRate.PayPerValue3], 0))) AS PayPerValue
FROM ActualPaymentDaysRate INNER JOIN ReceivePaymentLine 
ON <Match Condition>
INNER JOIN Invoice 
ON ReceivePaymentLine.AppliedToTxnTxnID = Invoice.TxnID
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But there is no match key between ActualPaymentDaysRate with other table. ActualPaymentDaysRate table has only one record (and the field of "ActualPaymentDay1, ActualPaymentDay2, ActualPaymentDay3 are related to DateDiff("d",[Invoice]![TxnDate],[ReceivePaymentLine]![TxnDate]) AS ActualPaymentDays. I want to make dynamic IF (Now the IF condition for ActualPaymentDays<90, ActualPaymentDays<120 and ActualPaymentDays<365 are all hardcode on query). I want Admin to be able to change those numbers (90, 120 and 365) on the data table (ActualPaymentDaysRate) then run the report.