# LEFT JOIN SQL Join Expression not supported

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, left-join

I can't find what is wrong with this SQL expression:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PNLTERM.TAGSTRIP, TERMS.TERM, PNLTERM.STRIPSEQ, TERMS.WIRENO, 
TERMS.REF, TERMS.MFG, TERMS.CAT, TERMS.BLOCK, PNLTERM.HDL, TERMS.WDBLKNAM, 
TERMS.JUMPER_ID, WIREFRM2.WIRELAY
FROM (PNLTERM LEFT JOIN TERMS ON PNLTERM.LINKTERM = TERMS.LINKTERM) 
INNER JOIN WIREFRM2 ON TERMS.HDL = WIREFRM2.COMP_HDL;
```

It is something to do with the left join on PNLTERM/TERMS; as it works with a inner and right join but not with a left join.
The error is 'Join expression not supported'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Might be those unnecessary brackets.

Comment: Everything else I've read seem to indicate these errors happen with not enough brackets!

Comment: That is just to indicate that the left join is executed first

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381949/sql-join-expression-not-supported

Comment: The brackets are not necessary in order for the query to be semantically and syntactically correct. The query optimizer is virtually always going to do a better job of figuring out the most efficient order of operations (based on indexes and statistics) than you are.

Comment: @sqluser how does the article you referenced at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381949/sql-join-expression-not-supported relate specifically to this question?

Comment: Your left join must be the last in the query. It is a limitation of access

Comment: @cha, thankyou. If I leave the left join last and leave out the brackets, will it still execute that first?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MS Access has some rules regarding its use of LEFT/RIGHT joins with the INNER joins. Specifically, there is a rule regarding its mix. It is explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208854%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

> A LEFT JOIN or a RIGHT JOIN may be nested inside an INNER JOIN, but an INNER JOIN may not be nested inside a LEFT JOIN or a RIGHT JOIN.

You have a couple of options: You can convert the second join to a left join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PNLTERM.TAGSTRIP, TERMS.TERM, PNLTERM.STRIPSEQ, TERMS.WIRENO, 
TERMS.REF, TERMS.MFG, TERMS.CAT, TERMS.BLOCK, PNLTERM.HDL, TERMS.WDBLKNAM, 
TERMS.JUMPER_ID, WIREFRM2.WIRELAY
FROM (PNLTERM LEFT JOIN TERMS ON PNLTERM.LINKTERM = TERMS.LINKTERM) 
LEFT JOIN WIREFRM2 ON TERMS.HDL = WIREFRM2.COMP_HDL;
```

Or, you can change the query, so that the INNER join comes first:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PNLTERM.TAGSTRIP, TERMS.TERM, PNLTERM.STRIPSEQ, TERMS.WIRENO, 
TERMS.REF, TERMS.MFG, TERMS.CAT, TERMS.BLOCK, PNLTERM.HDL, TERMS.WDBLKNAM, 
TERMS.JUMPER_ID, WIREFRM2.WIRELAY
FROM (WIREFRM2 INNER JOIN TERMS ON TERMS.HDL = WIREFRM2.COMP_HDL) 
RIGHT JOIN PNLTERM ON PNLTERM.LINKTERM = TERMS.LINKTERM;
```

Comment: Thanks @cha, if I changed that INNER JOIN in your second suggestion to a RIGHT JOIN, I think this would achieve my desired result

Comment: Oh, now another problem. It seems I can't put the RIGHT JOIN last?

Comment: Looking at your query I can see that two LEFT joins should be more appropriate for your situation

Comment: I need to include all records in the PNLTERM table. As far as I can work out, this can only be achieved with a RIGHT join, or my first method of putting a LEFT join first?